# Get matrix elements with indices stored in array without a cycle

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, indexing

Suppose we have a two-dimensional matrix `A` and two vectors `a = (a1,a2,...,an)`, `b = (b1,b2,...,bn)`. My task is to get a vector which contains the elements of `A` with the indices taken from the vectors `a`,`b`, i.e. `ans = (A(a1,b1), A(a2,b2), A(a3,b3),..., A(an,bn))`. Is there a vector operation for that, so I can make it in one operation instead of using cycles?

Using a matrix type here is not essential, `A` could be cell array, table or whatever, the only important thing is to allow me to form the vector I've described.

The thing that complicates the matter is that I need not to have just the values, but on the contrary to change the selected matrix elements, so I shouldn't extract them from the matrix.

At the moment I have only one variant on my mind, which is not very clever: to linearize the matrix A and take the values from the vector, in the format `A_vectorized(index_vector)`, where `index_vector` is formed from combinations of indices from `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `sub2ind` to convert from subscripts `(a,b)` to linear indices. You can get your answer as

```
A(sub2ind(size(A),a,b))
```